# JavaFX 2 Drag ImageView to a Button

Tags: java, events, button, javafx, imageview

All I want is to capture when I drop ImageView on Button:
[image]

I tried to the following:

```
button.setOnDragOver(event -> {
                System.out.println("drop");
            });
button.setOnMouseDragReleased(event -> {
                System.out.println("drop");
            });
```

And nothing seems to work, any ideas?

Comment: Can you specify what exactly you want to accomplish when image view is dropped on the button

Comment: Set the button text to *

Answer (score 0):

Try The following code to create an event handler for handling event of dragging the image over the button:

```
button.setOnDragOver(new EventHandler() {
        @Override
        public void handle(final DragEvent event) {
            mouseDragOver(event);
        }
    });
```

Then declare the event method which needs to be executed when event occurs

```
private void mouseDragDropped(final DragEvent e) {
  System.out.println("drop");
}
```

Comment: Your segregation had some error, I tried the following without success:
`c.setOnDragOver(new EventHandler() {
                    @Override
                    public void handle(Event event) {
                        mouseDragDropped((EventHandler) event);
                    }
                });
private void mouseDragDropped(EventHandler e) {
        System.out.println("drop");
    }`

Comment: did you add all required import file statements?